# How to solve this error Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined [bcryptjs]

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

I am using bcryptjs to hash passwords but I'm getting an error like this in console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

What I have done so far is just install in my main project folder npm install bcryptjs after that it create a folder called `node_modules` and then add a line like this: `var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');` in `main.js` but this is not working.

Any sugestion

Comment: How are you running it? `node main.js`?

Comment: Are you calling this from browser side, browsers don't have require.  You need to transpile node.js modules for use in the browser.  You do have node.js as your tag, so it would seem strange `require` is not defined.

Comment: no, I am running it in chrome. I know what you are going to say, that require is not browser function I know that, I need the step on how to solve that

Comment: @Keith how I can transpile node.js?

Comment: I use webpack.. https://webpack.js.org/

Comment: @Keith I install browserify but I'm stuck on the <script> tag part

Comment: what <script> tag part, are you able to post what you have done so far.   The <script> tag should just be in your HTML, no in your Javascript.

Comment: I am doing the exact same thing like in http://browserify.org/ follow the guide

Comment: So the output javascript that browserfy created place somewhere on your website, and then in your your index.html add the <script> tag and point it at the javascript file.

Comment: I solved this but is to slow and I have to build and run everytime I save my files. Thanks anyways I'll find another way to use bcryptjs